# Adding JAVA_HOME disables cordova

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

When I add my JAVA_HOME environment variable, commands `cordova` and `ionic` quit working (windows).  If I delete the environment variable, the commands work again.

Strangely, if I don't have it there and run `cordova run android --device` it says that `JAVA_HOME` is `JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_45`.  I have no idea where it is getting that from because it's not in user variables or system variables.  I have both `1.8.0_73` and `1.8.0_45` installed.

[image]

Comment: Try adding C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin, also take a look at [this](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android)

Comment: Unfortunately did not fix it :(

Comment: did you check the link that I gave to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete `1.8.0_45` version and restart your computer. I think now the problem is fixed ?